# What does "half the friendship in the world" mean in this passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "half the friendship in the world" mean in this passage from George MacDonald's *Paul Faber Surgeon* (search [here](http://archive.org/stream/paulfabersurgeon12387gut/12387.txt) for more context)?

> But for money and the need of it, there would not be half the
>   friendship in the world. It is powerful for good when divinely used.
>   Give it plenty of air, and it is sweet as the hawthorn; shut it up and
>   it cankers and breeds worms.

I understand that the second half of this passage is referring to the polarity of money as either good or evil, depending on how it is used. But what is the first sentence talking about? Money and the need of it provides friendship in the world? Is it saying that without money and its need, there would not be half the friendship in the world? Or is it saying that money and its need diminishes friendship in the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it saying that without money and its need, there would not be half the friendship in the world?"

That's almost the verbatim wording from the passage, so I would say yes. :)

- "but for" → "except for" ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but_for))
- "there would not be X" → "X would not exist"

So the beginning of the passage could be paraphrased:

> Half of the friendship in the world would not exist except for the fact that there is money and people need it.